# How much of "Mock the Week" is scripted vs. improvised?

Tags: comedy, mock-the-week, panel-shows

Mock the Week is a British panel show where comedians make jokes about last week's events. It's made to feel as though it's all improvised banter (or at the very least jokes they told their friends over beer in the days preceding the recording).

One of the parts involves some of the participants doing a short stand up bit on a topic chosen, seemingly at random. Another part is the participants making jokes in the form of "unlikely thing to hear in whatever scenario", which often involves two scenarios given (first the one, and after it is exhausted a bit, the second). Both of these feel somehow as they are coming with these on the spot.

**However!** You can sometimes see that some people have notes on their hands or hidden on the desk. There are graphics prepared for some of the jokes. And in one outtakes part, a participant in the "unlikely things to hear" said something that made no sense, and then it was clarified (through a later outtake) that what he said was supposed to be in the second scenario.

All this raises the question, how much do the panelists know in advance? Do they know who is going to the stand up challenge, or what the topics might be? In other words, how far is this from a proper improv show (e.g. Whose Line)?

Comment: I have no idea what tags to use, please help!

Comment: The tags look good enough to me.

Comment: I know they do get preparation time; but I don't know where I found this information to provide citations… the hunt is on ;) btw, the stand-up routines, they know the topic before-hand, so they pick a part of their routine that covers it. They don't have to write it all fresh. How does Hugh always know the 'real answer'? How does he manage to keep up with the voiceover for the Queen & Prince Phil? btw, what makes you think any show is **all** truly improv??

Comment: @Tetsujin: Thanks! I guess it's the part of me that thinks that Ryan Stiles is awesome.

Comment: The point is to create a funny show, not to create a "honest" quiz. I'm sure some of those stand-up bits are even short excerpt from a comedian's actual routine, thus you see them tell stories that might only barely be related to the subject that is picked.

Comment: @BCdotWEB: I should probably clarify. I don't think that the stand-up bits are supposed to be improvised. But even if I have a story about a relationship in my repertoire, they jump in quite quickly. The "let's spin the wheel" makes it seem like it's at the very least unknown who will talk about what topic, but then you realise that the stories are prepared in advance, and one only has to wonder if the wheel part is also just for show (and the actual choice was already decided before filming).

Comment: @Tetsujin: The voiceovers are most likely prerecorded. It doesn't really change the quality of the comedy but it allows Hugh to know the timing of the sentences (e.g. not starting a long sentence if a camera cut is coming soon). Quite commonly, Hugh sets up for a joke that is then completed visually, and he wouldn't be able to do that if he didn't know the footage in advance - definitely not as frequent as it happens.

Comment: I always assumed for the standup challenge that they took material from other routines they already have which fit the topic - sometimes they tangent off from the topic a little because maybe they don't have anything that quite fits.

Comment: @colmde: Yes, that was my guess as well. But it's a different challenge if you know if advance what bit you're going to take, and coming with it on the spot. And if you know in advance which bit you're going to take, does that mean that they actually decide who takes which topic? "Let's spin the wheel" may very well be all smoke and mirrors, it's not an actual wheel that they spin (which can also be rigged quite easily).

Comment: @Tetsujin: After watching the seasons available on Netflix, half the time "the correct answer" is just naming the person in the picture, or something very famous from the news. So that's really not something I expect to need a production note to the panelist ("That is... Theresa May.") also there were a lot of Nish Kumar getting "the right answer".

Comment: @Inkblot - that's actually changed in recent seasons - It is pretty much always Hugh that gives the (totally unimportant) right answer (I think Andy Parsons used to do some, but my memory is hazy), but he did used to explain it fairly well. In recent times, yes, he's changed to "That's Theresa May". The 'right' answer was always unimportant, as the audience would be expected to know from a very recent well-publicised current event. I guess they just gave up on 'accuracy'.